# Grub2 and mounting a rootfs

Tags: linux, grub2, root-filesystem

I am trying to boot a machine using a version of the kernel (linux-2.6.32.68 - unpatched) that I have compiled and mount a small root filesystem.

I have created a small ext2 file system using the following:

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=rootfs.img bs=1k count=8000
mkfs.ext2 -i 1024 -F rootfs.img
```

I have populated in accordance with the following guide: http://blog.braslavsky.org/2010/01/embedded-linux-from-scratch-in-90.html
So it has the necessary busybox binaries and an init script to run.

This all works fine when launching using QEMU to emulate a real machine i.e. the Kernel loads and mounts the rootfs e.g.:

```
qemu-system-x86_64 -m 64 -hda ./rootfs.img -kernel linux-2.6.32.68/arch/x86/boot/bzImage -append "root=/dev/sda init=/sbin/init"
```

However, I've tried to add my kernel binary (bzImage) and my rootfs (rootfs.img) to a VM running fedora 22 so that I can boot it using that.
I've added the kernel to /boot and renamed it as appropriate. I then ran grub update or similar to regenerate /boot/grub2/grub.cfg and it successfully picked up my new kernel.   All seemed well and I now get a boot loader menu for the VM.

I've tried to manually edit the grub.cfg file to mount my file system e.g.
    root=/rootfs.img.

However, when trying to boot the kernel, it loads but stalls complaining that it can't mount that particular VFS and throws a kernel panic.

Any ideas?  Am I specifying my root file system incorrectly?  I've even tried converting my rootfs to ext3, but it does not make a difference.

Is my approach doomed to fail?